# R: Grouping records by index and update records

Tags: r

I would like to group the records by setID.x. Then for each grouping, I would like to take the sum of VAR1 and VAR2, then determine which is the higher number and get the ratio of the two. For example, if sum(VAR1) is greater than sum(VAR2) then ratio=sum(VAR1)/sum(VAR2). Once the ratio is calculated, the values of VAR2 (lower number) will be multiplied by the ratio. The adjusted values will form new variables. In effect, new variables will now have the same total. How do I do this in R? Here's a sample dataset:

```
dput(testfile)
structure(list(setID.x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), VAR1 = c(NA, 30.96, 0.85, 17.78, 30.96, 0.85, 
1.23, 6.92, 0.64, 2.5, 1.52, 4.11, 0.35), VAR2 = c(NA, 0, 0.18, 
4.11, 0, 0.18, 1.09, 0.9, 2.24, 6.96, 8.89, 17.78, 3.72)), .Names =     c("setID.x", 
"VAR1", "VAR2"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = structure(list(setID.x = structure(list(), class =     c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), VAR1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), VAR2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), newVAR1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), newVAR2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("setID.x", "VAR1", "VAR2", "newVAR1", 
    "newVAR2")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"),     class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

here is my expected output:

```
dput(output)
  structure(list(setID.x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), VAR1 = c(NA, 30.96, 0.85, 17.78, 30.96, 0.85, 
  1.23, 6.92, 0.64, 2.5, 1.52, 4.11, 0.35), VAR2 = c(NA, 0, 0.18, 
  4.11, 0, 0.18, 1.09, 0.9, 2.24, 6.96, 8.89, 17.78, 3.72), newVAR1 = c(NA, 
  30.96, 0.85, 17.78, 30.96, 0.85, 1.23, 6.92, 2.78, 10.85, 6.6, 
  17.84, 1.52), newVAR2 = c(NA, 0, 2.08, 47.51, 0, 3.31, 20.07, 
  16.57, 2.24, 6.96, 8.89, 17.78, 3.72)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
  "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), .Names = c("setID.x", 
  "VAR1", "VAR2", "newVAR1", "newVAR2"), spec = structure(list(
      cols = structure(list(setID.x = structure(list(), class =       c("collector_integer", 
      "collector")), VAR1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
      "collector")), VAR2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
      "collector")), newVAR1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
      "collector")), newVAR2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
      "collector"))), .Names = c("setID.x", "VAR1", "VAR2", "newVAR1", 
      "newVAR2")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
      "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Where exactly did you get stuck? What do you want to do with the NA values?

Comment: I'm not sure how you get a lot of the values in the expected output. It seems like there's a disconnect between the output example and the narrative. If you could check for either a mistake in the output or add more narrative to clarify using some specific examples from the output that would be helpful.

Comment: i have edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's quick way of doing it with dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
testfile %>%
  group_by(setID.x) %>% 
  mutate(sumVar1 = sum(VAR1, na.rm=T), sumVar2 = sum(VAR2, na.rm =T), test = sumVar1>sumVar2,
         ratio = ifelse(test, sumVar1/sumVar2, sumVar2/sumVar1),
         newVAR1 = ifelse(test, VAR1, VAR1*ratio), newVAR2 = ifelse(test,VAR2*ratio, VAR2)) %>%
  select(setID.x, VAR1, VAR2, newVAR1, newVAR2)
```

You get the result as follows.

```
# Source: local data frame [13 x 5]
# Groups: setID.x [3]
# 
# setID.x  VAR1  VAR2 newVAR1   newVAR2
# <int> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1        1    NA    NA      NA        NA
# 2        1 30.96  0.00   30.96  0.000000
# 3        1  0.85  0.18    0.85  2.080699
# 4        1 17.78  4.11   17.78 47.509301
# 5        2 30.96  0.00   30.96  0.000000
# 6        2  0.85  0.18    0.85  3.314654
# 7        2  1.23  1.09    1.23 20.072074
# 8        2  6.92  0.90    6.92 16.573272
# 9        3  2.24  0.64    2.24  2.778246
# 10       3  6.96  2.50    6.96 10.852522
# 11       3  8.89  1.52    8.89  6.598333
# 12       3 17.78  4.11   17.78 17.841546
# 13       3  3.72  0.35    3.72  1.519353
```